# REST API for CometD

Tags: cometd

I'm currently using a CometD server along with a jQuery client implementation. What I'll like to know is if there is any efficient way to have a REST API in my server for the client to retrieve information (i.e. a string). I only need to retrieve the string once, after which I no longer need to use the service anymore.

Currently how I'm doing it is to use a service channel and add a listener for it in the server. I then let my client send a random message to this channel. Upon receiving the message, the server will retrieve the string and broadcast it back to the client using the same channel.

However, I find it a very roundabout way and besides, there is no need for the client to listen to the channel any more upon receiving the string. Is there any better way to do it?

Update: I'm also using the server for other real-time channels, which was why I chose CometD for its publish-broadcast function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to return the string information back to the client that requested it, and you do not need to broadcast this information to other clients, then you do not need [CometD](http://cometd.org): a simple Servlet is enough (you don't even need REST).

If, on the other hand, you need to broadcast the string information to multiple clients, then CometD is the right tool for the job, and after all it's not that complicated, for what it does.

Client:

```
cometd.init("http://server/cometd");
cometd.subscribe("/info", function(m)
{
    // Do something with the message, then disconnect
    cometd.disconnect();
});
cometd.publish("/service/myservice", {});
```

Server:

```
@Service
class MyService
{
    @Inject
    private BayeuxServer bayeux;
    @Session
    private LocalSession session;

    @Listener("/service/myservice")
    public void processMyService(ServerSession s, ServerMessage m)
    {
        String info = retrieveInfo();
        // Broadcast
        bayeux.getChannel("/info").publish(session, info, null);
    }
}
```

Here you can find further information on CometD [annotated services](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_services_annotated).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I also have other channels which do make use of the CometD architecture. I do know of the servlet method, but is it possible to integrate it with the CometD server?